# HoloLens2 Voice Commands ARM64

Tags: vuforia, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm trying to implement voice commands using the following documentation: https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/InputEvents.html#input-event-interface-example for a HoloLens 2 application. The code is nearly identical to the examples, except I'm also registering to the input system similar to the "Global input registration example" for speech.

If I build an app package targeted for ARM, the voice commands work great; however, the version of Vuforia we're using doesn't have an ARM .dll, so we're forced to use ARM64. When I build an app package targeted for ARM64, Vuforia works great, but I can't get the voice commands to be recognized anymore. We're currently using MRTK v2.8.0.0.

I've done a bit of google searching and found some related questions, but nothing quite like what we're experiencing. I've tried looking for an ARM VuforiaEngine.dll for the version of Vuforia we're using, but haven't had much luck. We're currently using version 10.7.2.

Comment: The document you are referring to is out of date, please refer to [Input events - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/input-events?view=mrtkunity-2022-05). There is an official sample - [Speech - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/speech?view=mrtkunity-2022-05#example-scene), you can try to build and deploy it as ARM64 to see if it works. If it doesn't work, please share your Unity version and HoloLens OS version.